# Ng Bootstrap Carousel Full-screen

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have an angular 5 application and I am using `Carousel component` from `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2"`. I want to preview pictures in full screen but when I press `f11`.  My picture look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufOVz.jpg). I do not know what css to apply in order to prevent the browser from showing the white empty line at the bottom.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: please share some code of yours though i have given the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add the styling to the image

```
img {
 height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add:

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.carousel,.item,.active{height:100%;}
.carousel-inner{height:100%;}
```